# Character pattern Oracle

Tags: sql

I have a column that stores data and need to find all records that follow a 4 non numeric and 7 numeric pattern.  Ex. ABCD1234567

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ([COLUMN1],'\D{4}?')
```

Comment: What seems to be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the string to start (`^`) with 4 non-digits (`\D{4}`), continue with seven digits (`\d{7}`) and end then (`$`):

```
REGEXP_LIKE (col, '^\D{4}\d{7}$')
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  Your explanations is much simpler than Oracle's documentation.